# python : sorting a dictionary using datetime as key

Tags: python

I am trying to read from a log file which has a timestamp with milliseconds as follows
and then inserting into a dictionary based on 'st_time' as key.

```
st_time = datetime.strptime(t_str[0],"%d/%b/%Y %H:%M:%S.%f")
final_dict[st_time] = line
for key in sorted(final_dict.iterkeys()):
    print "%s : %s" %(key,final_dict[key])
```

But I get this error below

```
for key in sorted(final.iterkeys()):


TypeError: can't compare datetime.datetime to tuple
```

Sample:
An entry from log file

```
Jul  1 03:27:12 syslog: [m_java]**[ 1/Jul/2013 03:27:12.818]**[j:[SessionThread <]^Iat com/avc/abc/magr/service/find.something(abc/1235/locator/abc;Ljava/lang/String;)Labc/abc/abcd/abcd;(bytecode:7)

t_str[0] --> ['29/Jun/2013 01:16:06.149']

st_time --> 2013-06-29 01:16:06.149000
```

Thanks for any help!

Comment: What other keys do you have in that dictionary?

Comment: none - I just extracted the datetime from the log to do sorting.

Comment: Print out the dictionary and show us the result.

Comment: {datetime.datetime(2013, 6, 28, 11, 14, 42, 128000): 'Jun 28 11:14:42  syslog: [m_fdr][28/Jun/2013 11:14:42.128][CaRsr\r\n', datetime.datetime(2013, 6, 29, 1, 16, 8, 150000): 'Jun 29 01:16:08 powertv syslog: [29/Jun/2013 01:16:08.150] nexus_hdmi_output: Attached Rx may be powered down... \r\n',..........}

Comment: At least one key in your dictonary is a tuple instead of a datetime.datetime instance. You could try finding them with "print [k for k in final_dict if not isinstance(k, datetime.datetime)]"

Answer (score 1):

```
st_time = datetime.strptime(t_str[0],"%d/%b/%Y %H:%M:%S.%f")
key = float(time.mktime(st_time.timetuple()) + st_time.microsecond / 1000000.0)
final_dict[key] = line
for key in sorted(final_dict.iterkeys()):
    print "%s : %s" %(key,final_dict[key])
```

The reason for your error is strptime returns a struct_time. Converting it to UNIX timestamp (which will be a float) should allow you to sort more easily.

Comment: Nope. This is losing 'millisecond' precision.     [28/Jun/2013 11:14:42.128]   &   [28/Jun/2013 11:14:42.008]   -- only one of the logs with these timestamps is making it to dictionary.

Comment: Its not. This is a floating point number. The part after the decimal is the milliseconds.

Comment: I take it back you are correct. final_dict[float(time.strftime('%s.%f', st_time))] = line should work

Comment: Ive updated the answer, yeah for some reason it sets the decimal part to zero when using the previous method. That is unfortunate!

Comment: final[float(time.strftime('%s.%f',st_time))] = line
TypeError: argument must be 9-item sequence, not datetime.datetime

Comment: Ah so many problems.... :) float(time.mktime(st_time.timetuple()) + st_time.microsecond / 1000000.0) WILL WORK!

Comment: sorry it still is giving trouble to me.  -    for key in sorted(final.iterkeys()):
TypeError: can't compare datetime.datetime to float

Comment: see updated code. You should be able to figure it out from there, sorting a list of floats.

Answer (score -1):

If you're using a dictionary and hoping that it will be sorted in any manner, then you're using the wrong datatype.

There are many other sub-types of dictionary, that do support sorting, but I would recommend using a two-element tuple instead.

```
sorted_times = sorted([(k, v) for k, v in final_dict.items()])
```

It will automatically sort on the first entry of each tuple, which should be the datetime.